# how to fold / collapse sections of a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I hope to fold the tableview cell , when I tap the red button

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if([[appDelegate.gHomeHeaderArray_AppDelegate objectAtIndex:section] getIsFolded]==true)      
    {       
        return 0;           
    }
    else
    {
       return 1;      
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if([[appDelegate.gHomeHeaderArray_AppDelegate objectAtIndex:section] getIsFolded ]==true)
    {   
       return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        return 1; 
    }
}

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender;
{
    if([[appDelegate.gHomeHeaderArray_AppDelegate objectAtIndex:v] getIsFolded])
    {
         [[appDelegate.gHomeHeaderArray_AppDelegate objectAtIndex:v] setIsFolded:false];
    }
    else
    {
        [[appDelegate.gHomeHeaderArray_AppDelegate objectAtIndex:v] setIsFolded:true];
    }
    [listview reloadData];
}
```

When I tape a button, it will check if set the numberOfRowsInSection to 0

it works, but the tableview cell move to under another header view rather than hiding.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the following links it describe about collapse functionality of UITableview

1. https://github.com/floriankrueger/iOS-Examples--UITableView-Combo-Box/zipball/master
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240435/Reusable-collapsable-table-view-for-iOS
3. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

This might be the kind of animation you are looking for:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mpfoldtransition

You may have to tweak it a little bit, but it's worth it if you like how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //use this method to reload the table,
    - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
    //Pass list of indexpaths need to be reloaded, and pass UITableViewRowAnimationBottom this parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the first example: https://github.com/floriankrueger/iOS-Examples--UITableView-Combo-Box/zipball/master
it is straightforward. and here is a summary

1. save section open or close state somewhere
2. when row 0 is select, add or delete rows with animation

   ```
   NSMutableArray *indexPathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
       NSIndexPath *path0 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row]+i inSection:[indexPath section]];
       [indexPathArray addObject:path0];
   }
   [self.tableView beginUpdates];
   [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
   //[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
   [self.tableView endUpdates];
   ```
3. get the selected cell and toggle the drop down arrow
4. deselect cell

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a folding list in Swift using the following approach.  When a section is folded I still display a single row (the header) and so always return at least 1 for the section row count.  This means when folded a section doesn't disappear.  When folded status changes we use tableView.reloadSections to update the relevant parts of the table (with animations)

For this example I use the following variables in the code below:

sectionHeadings[] : an array of section headings

sectionVisible[] : an array of Bool flags indicating whether that section is folded

sectionSubheadings[][] : for each section an array of subheadings that should appear when a section is unfolded.

The relevant methods for tableView are then as follows:

First return the number of sections based on our section heading array.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return sectionHeadings.count
}
```

We decide how many rows are in a section depending on whether it is folded or not.  If it is folded then we still show one cell - this is the section header and it is always visible:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if sectionVisible[section]{
        return sectionSubheadings[section].count + 1
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}
```

Then when we select a cell we check the current status and open or close the current section.  This same behaviour can also be attached to a button.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // if we are selecting a sub heading then this means we want to actually process the click
    // if we are selecting a section heading (index 0) then we want to open or close the section
    if indexPath.row == 0{

        // this is a section heading

        // if the section is already open then we don't want to reopen it
        let bOpening = !sectionVisible[indexPath.section]

        // bunch all our updates together
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        // need to close any existing open sections
        // NB this is optional behaviour and ensures there is only one section open at a time
        for (var i:Int = 0;i<sectionVisible.count;i++){
            if sectionVisible[i]{
                sectionVisible[i] = false
                tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: i), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            }
        }

        if bOpening{
            // open this chapter
            sectionVisible[indexPath.section] = true
            tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }

        tableView.endUpdates()

    }else{

        // we have clicked a visible sub heading so process this as required
    }
}
```

When providing cells in tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath you can then return either a header row or a subheading row depending on the index value.  Index=0 is the header, Index=n+1 is the nth subheading

Answer (score 0):

Really simple way of doing this in Swift 2 (though it's nothing unique to Swift; could easily be done in Obj-C too):

```
extension UITableView {
    public func indexPathsForRowsInSection(section: Int) -> [NSIndexPath]? {
        return (0..<self.numberOfRowsInSection(section)).map{NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: section)}
    }
}
```

Assuming `sender` is a `UISwitch`, though you could do this with any Bool value:

```
if let indexPaths = remindersTableView.indexPathsForRowsInSection(section) where !sender.on {
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Middle)
} else if let indexPaths: [NSIndexPath] = (0..<numberOfRowsYouWantToAdd).map({NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: section)}) where sender.on {
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Middle)
}
```